# iOS crash undefined

Tags: ios, crash

Don't see any issues relating to MY app.  And this only happens when coming back to the app, sometimes, never in the simulator.

Any ideas?:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xd03beb08
Crashed Thread:  7

Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36f22f78 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreFoundation                  0x34ea2e90 CFRetain + 76
2   CFNetwork                       0x379a6f30 HostBase::lock() + 8
3   CFNetwork                       0x379a6676 DispatchHost::performInvocation(void const*) + 6
4   CFNetwork                       0x379a61c8 __setupTCPConnection_block_invoke_2 + 284
5   libsystem_network.dylib         0x32c2cac0 __tcp_connection_notify_complete_block_invoke_1 + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x37886c52 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x378927b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 256
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35b45df4 _pthread_wqthread + 288
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35b45cc8 start_wqthread + 0
```

Comment: This occurs when your app is sent to the background and you come back from that?

Comment: yes but not always...i send the app to the background and then i open a few other apps, then come back to mine and this sometimes happens on this view

Comment: Post your `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidUnload`, etc.